# Typeguard to narrow property of this

Tags: typescript

Is there a syntax to have a type guard narrow something like `this['some_property']`?

I know it is possible to just pass the narrowing-target as an argument, but figured maybe I'd be able to clean that up a bit.

```
type A = {a: number};
type B = {b: string};

class Foo {
    union_member: A | B;
    constructor(val: A | B) { this.union_member = val; }

    narrow_a() : this['union_member'] is A { // invalid
        return true;
    }

    also_no({union_member} : this = this) : union_member is A { // invalid
        return true;
    }

    goal() {
        if (this.narrow_a()) {
            this.union_member.a + 42 /* ... */;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't guard on an individual field, but a guard on `this` will suffice, if we define an appropriate interface.

```
interface UnionIsA {
    union_member: A;
}
```

Then we can write `narrow_a` as

```
narrow_a() : this is UnionIsA {
    return true;
}
```

And `goal` will now compile. (Note that you do have to do `this.narrow_a()`, not just `narrow_a()`; that's a Javascript quirk and has nothing to do with the type system)

```
goal() {
    if (this.narrow_a()) {
        this.union_member.a + 42 /* ... */;
    }
}
```

Comment: nifty. I was worried your technique would narrow the whole object to just those members of the interface, but that does not happen. this works well, thanks.